# Silly question: make deuterium, tritium and Oxygen-17 and Oxygen-18 from nuclear waste

Tags: nuclear-physics, radioactivity, nuclear-engineering

Here is a silly question. Atoms of Nuclear waste isotopes usually have extra neutrons. Can regular hydrogen and oxygen come into contact with those atoms and take the extra neutrons away? Then the radioactive waste elements go to their stable isotopes and there is a source of deuterium, heavy oxygen and heavy water which has its use in nuclear reactor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking whether it would be possible to take some neutron-enriched nuclear waste and put it in contact with isotopes that can absorb an extra neutron with becoming radioactive. The answer to that question is "not easily." It costs about 8 MeV to remove a neutron from a nucleus; those sorts of energies are only available in nuclear reactions.

It *is* possible to choose materials for neutron shielding which don't activate very much. A common choice is polyethylene plastic mixed with boron carbide: in that material most of the neutron capture is $\rm ^{10}B\to{}^{11}B$, and to a lesser extent $\rm^1H\to {}^2H$.

A major contributor to long-lived, high-activity waste is plutonium, which is produced when neutrons capture on uranium (especially on U-238) without inducing a fission. That's a hard reaction to avoid, since putting neutrons on uranium is the operating mode for a reactor.

Comment: Would sticking a neutron to a stable isotope of a light element (proton, oxygen-16 atom) release energy? If yes, can this energy compensate for the use of energy in that 8 MeV?

Comment: The energy released by thermal (effectively zero-energy) neutrons capturing on some nucleus is the same as the “neutron separation energy” for the daughter nucleus. These are tabulated at, for example, the [NNDC](http://www.nndc.bnl.gov). A [related answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/509248/44126). There is a lot of variation in neutron separation energies, but interaction with an 8 MeV beam is when the safety people start checking for neutron activation of stuff in the neighborhood of the accelerator.